# Callout label with formatting issue

Tags: output-formatting, labeling

Here is my code...

```
ListPlot[{{1, 1}}, LabelingFunction->(Callout["cm^-1", Above] &)]
```

Except I write "cm^-1" as "cm ctrl+^ -1" so that it looks like
"$cm^{-1}$"

Why, then, does it look like this?

[image]

Comment: Hmm... This doesn't seem to change things for me

Comment: Can you copy your code from the notebook "as input text"? What version are you using?